# How to sent Email via C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I am trying to make a forgot password system in C# windows forms. I have an EmailService.cs file but can't send an email, It this code correct? I left the mailaddress and password empty due to security issues. Th application uses A mongoDB database

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System;


namespace Logic
{


    public class EmailService
    {
        public void SendEmail(string recipient, string subject, string body)
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("", "The Garden Group");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(recipient);
            // This password should be retrieved securely from a configuration file or environment variable
            const string fromPassword = "";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log or handle the exception here
                    // For example, you could log to console or to a file
                    Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
                    throw; // Re-throwing the exception is optional depending on how you want to handle it.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a windows forms with this function (something wrong is displayed):

```
 private void getTokenButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = emailTextBox.Text;
            // Call the correct method to request a password reset
            bool requestSent = userService.RequestPasswordReset(email);
            if (requestSent)
            {
                tokenErrorLabel.Text = "If the email is registered, we will send a reset token to it.";
            }
            else
            {
                tokenErrorLabel.Text = "Something went wrong.";
            }
        }
```

This is the RequestPasswordReset function:

```
public bool RequestPasswordReset(string email)
        {
            if (!EmailExists(email))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Generate the reset token
            string token = GenerateResetToken();

            // Save the reset token in the database for later verification
            dao.SetResetToken(email, token);

            try
            {
                // Initialize your EmailService with the actual credentials and host information
                EmailService emailService = new EmailService();

                // Craft the body of the email
                string emailBody = $"Your password reset token is: {token}";

                // Send the email with the token
                emailService.SendEmail(email, "Password Reset Request", emailBody);

                // If SendEmail does not throw an exception, return true to indicate the email was sent
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception as needed
                Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);

                // Return false if there was a problem sending the email
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Gpt says the code is correct.

Comment: Just a tip (and unrelated to the question): Instead of "logging" to Console.WriteLine, use an _actual_ logging framework. Even if you'll just log to Console.

Comment: I had issue with gmail. I think gmail does not support sending over smtp any more.
Check outlook for instance

Comment: Read this SO answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32457468/3094533

Comment: I tried outlook and it worked! thx!